# IOException, not finding file

Tags: java, string, file-io, ioexception

I was hoping someone could explain why this will not work and what my solution might be.

I have tried the following to learn what happens:

```
  String s = "\\users\\udc8\\a4471\\My Documents\\MATLAB\\blockdiagram.xml";
  String st = "\\";
  String st2 = st + s;
  System.out.println(st2);
```

Giving me the following output:

```
\\users\udc8\a4471\My Documents\MATLAB\blockdiagram.xml
```

Which is the correct path to the file.
Then I try to parse this file using SAX and I get an IOEXception saying the file does not exist. I have tried using File and getPath(),getCanonicalPath() and getAbsolutePath(). 
When running the parser i get the msg:

```
Due to an IOException, the parser could not check \\users\udc8\a4471\My Documents\MATLAB\\blockdiagram.xml
```

This is the code starting the parsing:

```
try {
      XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
      parser.parse(st2);
      System.out.println(s + " is well-formed.");
    }
    catch (SAXException e) {
      System.out.println(s + " is not well-formed.");
    }
    catch (IOException e) { 
      System.out.println(
       "Due to an IOException, the parser could not check " 
       + s
      ); 
    }
```

Running a similar program that does not have its own messege the following error messege is returned:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\users\udc8\a4471\workspace\SAX Intro\users\udc8\a4471\My Documents\MATLAB\blockdiagram.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

The file has no special restrictions (as far as I can see), Nothing ticked in looking at file properties and I can manually re-write the content.
Any ideas?

Comment: When you get an exception, print the exception, not just some vague message if your own devising. The actual exception message tells you exactly what the problem was.

Comment: do you realy expect the file to be under "\\users\udc8\a4471\workspace\SAX Intro\users\udc8\a4471\My Documents\MATLAB\blockdiagram.xml" if you ask me that "users\udc8\a4471" part seems to be duplicated

Comment: @EJP the messege I get is posted further down, the parsing code is not my own from the start so I have copied code from a SAX tutorial. I only changed the parts that matters to input my file.

Comment: @user1902288 No I do not expect that to be the location, however thats what the parser.parse(st2); seems to read from even though st2 does not include the first part. It seems like parser.parse starts from current directory. How would one work around this?

Comment: I havent used Stax since years, i will try to make a simple example here to understand the issue. May i ask if you pack your application to a .jar and include the xml-file or just run it from your IDE to let your class access the file? Does it work if you put the blockdiagram.xml into the same folder as your .class that contains the parser code and just hand "blockdiagram.xml" as parameter to the parser?

Comment: I run it from the IDE. When I try to run it in the same folder I get it to work! Thanks, however I want to be able to choose a folder and iterate through each file. So this will not be a viable solution in the end.

Comment: Well if you have a UI for example using the FileChooser to let a user choose the file you will get the correct path from that FileChooser Dialog. I will provide further sample code soon (underlying OS is Windows).

Comment: The only message of interest here is the exception message. The message starting `Due to an IOException, the parser could not check ...` is of zero interest and shouldn't have been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is just because of your path has two \-signs too much in it. I recomend you give it a try with your variable s instead of s2 that has the additional \-signs added.

To be honest i just realized how less i know about paths in java, expecially when it comes to different OS.

I however managed to get it to run on a Windows machine like so:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

public class SaXSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SaXSample().run();
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("This class is located under: "+getAbsolutePath());

        // using absolut pathd
        String absolutPath = "D:\\temp\\Oki.xml";
        File f = new File(absolutPath);
        System.out.println("Does the file exist using the absolut path? -> "+f.exists());
        runSaX(absolutPath);

        // using relative path (i dont know why it knows which drive C:/, D:/ to take but my .class is running from the same drive as the .xml is in)
        String relativePath = "\\temp\\Oki.xml";
        File f2 = new File(relativePath);
        System.out.println("Does the file exist using the relative path? -> "+f2.exists());
        runSaX(relativePath);

        // using a "wrong" relative path:
        String wrongRelativePath = "\\\\temp\\Oki.xml";
        File f3 = new File(wrongRelativePath);
        System.out.println("File relative path: "+f3.getPath()+" , File absolut path: "+f3.getAbsolutePath());
        runSaX(wrongRelativePath);
    }

    private void runSaX(String path) {
        try {
            XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
            parser.parse(path);
            System.out.println(path + " is well-formed.");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println(path + " is not well-formed.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Due to an IOException, the parser could not check "
                            + path);
        }
    }

    private String getAbsolutePath() {
        java.security.ProtectionDomain pd = SaXSample.class
                .getProtectionDomain();
        if (pd == null)
            return null;
        java.security.CodeSource cs = pd.getCodeSource();
        if (cs == null)
            return null;
        java.net.URL url = cs.getLocation();
        if (url == null)
            return null;
        java.io.File f = new File(url.getFile());
        if (f == null)
            return null;

        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    }

}
```

Which in my case leads to this output (sorry i dont know how to format console output):

```
This class is located under: D:\devjba\jba\bin

Does the file exist using the absolut path? -> true
D:\temp\Oki.xml is well-formed.

Does the file exist using the relative path? -> true
\temp\Oki.xml is well-formed.

File relative path: \\temp\Oki.xml , File absolut path: \\temp\Oki.xml
Due to an IOException, the parser could not check \\temp\Oki.xml
```

Since you implied in the comments that you wish to be able to select certain files or directorys i recomend you have a look at the JFileChooser. It is a simple way to let the user choose something that actually exists and will provide you the absolute path to the selected file/files.

**NOTE:** i have no clue why in the relative path-case the correct drive D:/ is used and not the other C:/

Comment: What happens in my case (Both in choosing file via file chooser, and just entering the string). The file f is in the path:path=f.getSelectedFile().AbsolutePath(); which is the correct path lets say "\\users\\udc8\\a4471\\My Documents\\MATLAB\\blockdiagram.xml" then I get an error saying
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\users\udc8\a4471\workspace\SAX Intro\users\udc8\a4471\My Documents\blockdiagram.xml.

Why does it add \workspace\SAX Intro in the path name and creates a path that clearly does not exist!
The input is parser.parse(path);